# Firefox Site Pinning

Tags: firefox, web, pinning

Is it possible to detect if your site is pinned in Firefox just as it is possible to do so in Internet Explorer 9 and above? If so, how do you do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: Mozilla does have a feature description page suggesting they're working on implementing this: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Features/CA_pinning_functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these APIs are Microsoft-specific.

After some research you may be able to create an add-on to do this:

See the [JumpListBuilder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIJumpListBuilder), [JumpListItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIJumpListItem) and [WinTaskbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWinTaskbar)
 APIs

Comment: I know that it is specific to IE9, but you would think that Mozilla would be working on a way to do it as well.

Comment: @PWF you can try searching the Bugzilla for "Jump Lists".